# How to stop Grid Child Elements from resizing on Grid.RenderTransform

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, grid, rendertransform

Okay, so I have a `Grid` with 4 child `Images`, each positioned in all four corners of the `Grid` like so.
[image: Grid with Children]

The purpose of the bottom two Child `Images`, is to stretch the grid. So when the user drags these corners, the `Grid` will stretch.

My problem is that the Children will stretch too, which I don't want.

[image: Stretched Grid]

Is there any way to ensure that the size of the children does not stretch with the `Grid`?

Thanks.

P.S. I could detach the Child `Images` from the `Grid`, but it is much simpler and more elegant this way as the x/y positions remain at the edges of the `Grid` perfectly, I just want to ensure they do not `Scale` with it, if possible.

**Create Grid and add Children**

```
//ImageGrid
ImageControl.Height = 500;
ImageControl.Width = 500;
ImageControl.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;

canvas.Children.Add(ImageControl);

ImageControl.Children.Add(tickBtn);
ImageControl.Children.Add(delBtn);
ImageControl.Children.Add(skewBtn);
ImageControl.Children.Add(strBtn);

ImageManipulation.Image_Drag = new CompositeTransform();
ImageManipulation.Image_Drag.CenterX = imW / 2;
ImageManipulation.Image_Drag.CenterY = imH / 2;

ImageControl.RenderTransform = ImageManipulation.Image_Drag;
strBtn.ManipulationDelta += ImageManipulation.resBtn_Manip;
skewBtn.ManipulationDelta += MaskManipulation.skewBtn_Manip;
dragControl.ManipulationDelta += ImageManipulation.movBtn_Manip;
```

**Manipulation Class**

```
public static CompositeTransform Image_Drag;

public static void resBtn_Manip(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e) 
{

    Mask_Drag.ScaleX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    Mask_Drag.ScaleY += e.Delta.Translation.X;
}

public static void movBtn_Manip(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Mask_Drag.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    Mask_Drag.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}

public static void skewBtn_Manip(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e) 
{

    Mask_Drag.ScaleX -= e.Delta.Translation.X;
    Mask_Drag.ScaleY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

    if (Mask_Drag.ScaleX < 0.5)

    {
        Mask_Drag.ScaleX = 0.5;
    }

    if (Mask_Drag.ScaleY < 0.5) 

    {
        Mask_Drag.ScaleY = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your xaml and the code that "stretches* the grid

Comment: The grid and images are added dynamically so there is no XAML, it is all written ion code-behind, pretty standard stuff but I'll add it to the post now.

Comment: The scaling of children is inevitable. One workaround may be to reverse scale the images.

Comment: if you want to make image cropper, you could refer this [library](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-ImageCropper-/blob/master/XamlBrewer.Uwp.Controls/Helpers/SelectedRegion.cs#L27).

Comment: @Muzib Are you able to post the code as an answer? My attempts have been unsuccessful and manually setting the Images ScaleX/Y to "1" during ManipulationDelta seemingly has no effect either